# Activate checkbox only when a particluar option in dropdown selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I want to activate the checkbox 'id=IsHeighest', only when the option 2 of the dropdown list is selected. Otherwise disable it. Can anyone help me?

```
 <spans>@MultiLang.Highest</spans>
 @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsHighest, new { Id = "IsHighest" })

<div class="col-md-3 ltrlable">
<span class="rtllable dri">@MultiLang.Status</span>
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.StatusId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Status, new { id = "VehicleStatus", @class = "form-control" })</div>
```

Comment: You need to use javascript/jquery. But disabled controls do not submit a value so that is probably not what you want (and you do not need to add `new { Id = "IsHighest" }` - its already added by the `CheckBoxFor()` method

Comment: I think you can use `$("#IsHighest").prop({ disabled: true });` on `change` event of `DropDownListFor` if other DDL values selected, but disabled input controls won't submit together with `BeginForm`, hence you may need different way to achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with jquery

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#IsHighest').prop('disabled', true);
     $('#StatusId').change(function () {
          var selectedValue= this.value;
          if(selectedValue=="2")
            {
              $('#IsHighest').prop('disabled', false);
            }
            else
             {
                $('#IsHighest').prop('disabled', true);
                }
            });
    });
```